# Schengen visa inquiry about "VIS" in remarks field

Tags: visas, schengen, austria

I got a schengen tourist visa for austria type C single entry and visa remark vis does that mean i can visit other other schengen countries during my travel ?
I am planning to go to Germany and Switzerland will there be any problems ?

Edit: i am going student exhange first in austria then going to the other countries

Comment: It's your 2nd visa, right? Hence "VIS".  Ignore it.  But does your itinerary include Austria? Or more probingly, why chose Austria if you are going to Germany and Switzerland?

Comment: Oh yeah i forgot to say i was going for student exchange in austria first sry and yeah its my 2nd time

Comment: Does this mean that it's ok to go other countries after austria ?

Comment: @Kaddah it's not about before or after - it's about whether you mentioned it in your application.

Comment: I mentioned i would like to travel at weekend and at the end but i didmt specify which countries in specific

Comment: @CMaster someone on a short-term student exchange can reasonably expect to be able to develop plans to visit other countries after the visa is granted.  It shouldn't matter whether this was mentioned in the application.

Answer (score 4):

You have a type "C" single-entry Schengen visa issued by Austria for a student programme there.

> does that mean i can visit other other schengen countries during my
>   travel?

Yes, of course you may. A single entry Schengen initializes at the time of your entry into the zone and is fully consumed when you exit the zone.  There are no controls within the zone and if the "Valid for" section of your visa is marked "Schengener Staaten" (German for "Schengen States") then you are free to move about the zone without restriction regardless if it is a weekend or not. If it does not have this type of validity, then you have a restricted movement visa and are constrained to only the locations listed in the "Valid for" field.

> and visa remark vis

This entry (i.e., "VIS") stands for "Visa Information System" and means you were not required to submit biometrics because your last successful application was within 5 years. You can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

When you applied for your Schengen visa, you had to explain the premise of your visit and to provide supporting documentation. If you try to use your visa for a completely different purpose, you may be refused entry.

*Example: If you have a single entry Schengen visa for all states from Italy for a tourist trip to Italy and Greece and show up at the Russian-Norwegian border, there may be questions. Unless you live in northern Russia, then going through Norway could be reasonable.*

When you are in the Schengen area, there are usually no internal border controls. You can enter any Schengen state which broadly matches the premise of your trip.

*Example: If you have a single-entry Schengen visa for all states from Austria for a study trip to Austria, you can decide to enter the Schengen area at Frankfurt airport in Germany, take an internal Schengen flight to Austria, do weekend trips to Switzerland and back to Germany, as long as the **main** purpose of your visit is still the study visit in Austria. That is all a single entry to the Schengen area.*

Comment: I realize that visas of "limited territorial validity" are supposed to be very rare, and probably are, but it seems like one still ought to tell people to check the "valid for" line at the top of the visa, to make sure it says *SCHENGENER STAATEN,* before making plans to travel to other Schengen countries.

Comment: @phoog, I've added it.