# Got French Schengen visa but no "VIS" after giving fingerprints

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I had my French Schengen visa interview 3 days ago (got the stamped visa and passport within two days, super efficient!). However there's no "VIS" written on the visa, even though I gave my fingerprints during the interview in US. I had presumed VIS would be written on the visa since I gave my fingerprints, or is it for something else? I do remember it took a while to take the fingerprints because the machine looked old and was taking a long time to read my fingerprints.

The next time I want to apply for a visa, do I need to go for an interview again just because the visa has no VIS on it?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68905/schengen-visa-inquiry-about-vis-in-remarks-field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"VIS" stands for "Visa Information System", it will appear on your second and subsequent visas where you were not required to submit biometrics because your last successful application was within 5 years.